# Why json.dumps fails when a dictionary contains a nested list?

Tags: python

I have flask method that is supposed to return an object with a list of results (which is a nested list).
However, flask jsonify method is throwing the following error:
`TypeError: Object of type builtin_function_or_method is not JSON serializable`
If serialise the list alone it works just fine, but if I include it as part of a dictionary it throws the above error.

The simplified method is like this:

```py
@app.route('/results/')
def results():
    db = get_db()
    ids = [int(id) for id in request.args.getlist('id')]

    some_results = get_results()

    result = [
        list(map(format_result, result_set))
        for result_set in some_results
    ]
    return {'result': {
        'id': id,
        'faces': result
    }}
```

I have other similar methods (that returns the same result structure) with the difference that this has a list of nested lists, that's the only difference.

Comment: The nested list is completely fine - you typo'd `id` when you meant `ids`. `id` is a built-in function.

Comment: I just noticed when I started changing the response to simplify it, removing everything but results. I didn't know that ID is a built-in python function. Thank you. Not sure if I should delete this question, since it is just a silly typo